# Specify a character set to .ttf files in http headers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, truetype

I tested my website performances on GTmetrix, and it asks me to specify a character set to .tff files in .htaccess, but i don't know how to fix it. Have you got an answer ?

Thanks for helping ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it - works for me:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf)$">
   ForceType 'font/opentype; charset=UTF-8'
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I've found another way to fix it : i've added this line `AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf` and i've added a line to specify the expire header : `ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf "access plus 2592000 seconds"` ;)